# How to handle turn of the year logically with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, logic, momentjs

Basically, I'm having a dynamic dropdown with x isoWeeks starting from the current one. A function is called when the isoWeek in the dropdown is selected.

```
var currentWeek = localStorage.getItem('currentWeek');
var currentYear = localStorage.getItem('currentYear');

var dropdownKalender = document.getElementById('dropdown_kalender');
var newWeek = dropdownKalender.options[dropdownKalender.selectedIndex].value;
localStorage.setItem('currentWeek', newWeek);
```

The `newWeek` variable is the selected week in `moment().isoWeek()` format. Now I'm in need of the logic for checking if the selected week is in the next year (or if it's back in the current year in case a future week has been selected before). I'm pretty sure it's about checking if a week is greater than the other, but as said before, I'm stuck at the logic part.

Comment: @Yogi There is no certain reason, I have been using it for some time now and pretty much like it, but reading your comment I might need to replace my moment.js codes.

Comment: moment.js has provided a list of [recommended alternatives](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/) for when you decide to modernize.